# Functional patterns in Prolog

Tags: prolog, meta-predicate

How do I create a predicate that takes another predicate and returns a derived version of it?

For example, pairwise predicates can be fairly mechanically extended to apply to lists:

```
all_whatever(_, []).
all_whatever(X, [Y|T]) :- 
    whatever(X, Y), 
    all_whatever(X, T).
```

What would be the definition of

```
pairwise_listwise(whatever, all_whatever).
```

If it's not possible/common/clunky/violates principles, what would be the alternative pattern?

Comment: If you are using SWI-Prolog are you seeking [library(yall): Lambda expressions](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=yall)? Or maybe something simpler such as [library(apply): Apply predicates on a list](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=apply)? Or maybe even more powerful such as [goal_expansion/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=goal_expansion/2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different ways to achieve what you want. The simplest, and likely preferred, way is to define a meta-predicate that takes any binary predicate and applies it to all elements of the list like so:

```
listwise(_,_,[]).
listwise(P,Y,[X|Xs]) :-
    call(P,Y,X),
    listwise(P,Y,Xs).
```

You can then call this as `listwise(whatever, Y1, Xs1)` to apply `whatever` to `Y1` and each element of `Xs1`.

This is made possible thanks to the `call/N` meta-predicate. Note that this meta-predicate can also take partially constructed goals as first argument, so that an alternative formulation could be:

```
listwise(_,[]).
listwise(P,[X|Xs]) :-
    call(P,X),
    listwise(P,Xs).
```

Which is then called as `listwise(whatever(Y1),Xs1)`. This version of the predicate is actually known as `maplist/2` instead of `listwise`, at least in SWI-Prolog (in module `library(apply)`) and SICStus Prolog (in module `library(lists)`).

The second way to achieve what you want (actually closer to what you where asking for) is to actually define a new predicate `all_whatever/2` using term expansion. Term expansion is a mechanism to rewrite terms when they are loaded (see e.g. for more details in SWI-Prolog: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=term_expansion/2). I am showing here the SWI-Prolog version, which is by defining a clause for the `term_expansion/2` predicate. This mechanism works differently in different systems or is altogether missing.

```
term_expansion(pairwise_listwise(PairPred,ListPred), ExpandedTerm) :-
    TerminalCall =.. [ListPred,_,[]],
    RecursiveCall =.. [ListPred,Y,[X|Xs]],
    SingleCall =.. [PairPred,Y,X],
    FinalCall =.. [ListPred,Y,Xs],
    ExpandedTerm = [TerminalCall, (RecursiveCall :- (SingleCall, FinalCall))].
```

In this clause, `ExpandedTerm` is a list defining the two clauses we want to define and all the terms in it are built from the predicate names using `=..`. One can then define the new predicate as follows:

```
pairwise_listwise(whatever, all_whatever).
```

When this code is loaded, that clause will be expanded and replaced by two clauses defining the new predicate `all_whatever`. And now one can call for instance `all_whatever(Y1,Xs1)`.

My preference goes to the first approach (conceptually simpler and works across Prolog versions) but I think it is also useful to be aware of the existence of the term expansion mechanism as well.

Comment: Term-expansion is not "slightly different in different systems." It's either missing altogether or substantially different.

Comment: @Paulo Moura. Thanks for the correction, I have changed the wording. (I am only familiar with SICStus and it felt not too different from SWI at first sight.)

Comment: Defining a predicate just by its expansion is a highly problematic move. Rather first take a real definition and then consider some optimization maybe using term expansion. But in case of doubt, the original definition is still here.

Comment: @false Can you elaborate on how this is highly problematic? Also I am not sure to understand how your suggestion would work in this case?

Comment: The more you rely on term expansion alone, the more you will depend on actual instantiations and the like. Like the tiny nasty details of `do`-loops. Or the way how meta-calls/cuts are resolved in a similarly nasty manner. In your current wording of course the problems are all eliminated (for the moment), as you insist qua univ on atoms for `PairPred` and `ListPred` only. But once you get over this, you will have problems.

Comment: Forgot to add the most prominent example: DCG! For long, they have been haunted by "clever" term expansions. Would they have been defined as an interpreter first that is a meta program and not just an ad hoc expansion, most of these problems would have never existed. Like lack of steadfastness.

Comment: @false has anyone written a MI version of DCG?

Comment: @ErikKaplun: For what purpose? DCGs now have similar glitches with *term-to-body* conversion just like the meta-call in general. But as long as there is no need for cut and the like, these obstacles can be avoided.

Comment: @ErikKaplun: See also chapter 6.3 Interpreters for DCGs of Prolog and Natural-Language Analysis.